# MySQL not allowing 'root@localhost' to access it

Tags: 22.04, mysql, lamp

I'm trying to set up MySQL server as part of a LAMP stack on Ubuntu Server 22.04, I have installed MySQL and whenever I try to run the commands:

```
~$ sudo mysql
or
~$ sudo mysql -u root -p
```

It returns the errors:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root@localhost' (using password: NO)
or
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root@localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I have tried a fresh install of `mysql-server` and also attempted to change the MySQL `root` password, but anytime I try to run any command for MySQL it will return one of the above mentioned errors.

This is my 2nd attempt to install MySQL server. The first time I had the exact same issue and was given the advice of attempting to remove and reinstall the repositories and try again but to no avail.

Comment: Run `sudo mysql_secure_installation` and try again.

Comment: according to the guide I am following, as of July 2022 running the secure installation without first changing the authentication method configuration it will just end up in a recursive loop however for me to be able to this I need to be able to open the mySQL prompt which it is denying me access to. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-22-04

Comment: Is this the first time you are installing MySQL on this machine?

Comment: 2nd attempt to install, the first time I had the exact same issue and was given the advice of attempting to remove and reinstall the repositories and try again but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is your second attempt to install MySQL, my suggestion is to do some cleanup and reinstall your MySQL:

***Warning:** This solution will delete all your data stored on the MySQL server!*

```
sudo apt purge mysql*
sudo apt autoremove

sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
```

Install MySQL:

```
sudo apt install mysql-server
```

After installing the server, doing `sudo mysql` should open MySQL.

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much friend :D

Comment: I am happy it worked. You can select this as the [Accepted Answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)